# Javascript not working properly in my WebView implementation

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to solve a problem with javascript and Disqus, I had to implement my WebView and all I do is just download the html from the url along with some string replaces

```
html = html.replaceFirst("<div", "<div id=\"headerApp\"></div><div");
html = html.replace("<head>", "<head> <style>"+cssContent +"</style>");
html = html.replace("class='hidden-phone'"," ");
html = html.replace("class=\"btn-mobile-pager visible-phone\"","class=\"btn-mobile-pager hidden-phone\"");
```

and then call

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("blarg://ignored", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

But the disqus comments are strange and look like this :

[image]

I believe this is some sort of javascript problem, here's what I do :

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {

            MyWebView myView = null;

            if(viewx instanceof MyWebView) {
                myView = (MyWebView) viewx;


                if(urlx.contains("https://twitter") || urlx.contains("action=em_fb_edit"))
                {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlx));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    myView.stopLoading();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (!urlx.startsWith("http://www.efficacemente")) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlx));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    return false;
                } else if (urlx.contains("@facebook")) {
                    //Fai l'intent a facebook se puoi
                    if (isAppInstalled("com.facebook.katana")) {
                        String uri = "fb://page/101189567644";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        String url = "http://www.facebook.com/101189567644";
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (urlx.contains("@twitter")) {
                    if (isAppInstalled("com.twitter.android")) {
                        String uri = "twitter://user?screen_name=EfficaceMente";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        String url = "http://www.twitter.com/Efficacemente";
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        return false;
                    }

                } else if (urlx.contains("@bookclub")) {
                    if (isAppInstalled("com.facebook.katana")) {
                        String uri = "fb://page/256384041207653";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        String url = "http://www.facebook.com/256384041207653";
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    myView.myLoad(urlx);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
    });
myWebView.clearCache(true);
myWebView.clearHistory();
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Where myWebView is an instance of MyWebView class that I created, where I simply download the html to the html and load it with loadDataWithBaseURL

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `blarg://ignored`, use the actual URL for the Web page, before you converted it. Your approach means that anything referenced via a relative URL (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.) cannot be loaded, because `WebView` does not know where those things are to be loaded from.